# Is the lint mode function available?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, linter

When I modify the "Severity of Pylint message type" parameter to "hint", the hints in the editing area are not obvious enough, only a few dots.

Error or Warning

Can the tilde color of the prompt be customized?

Answer (score 0):

If the squiggle for a problem in Pylint are not very long it's because Pylint doesn't provide more details than the line where the issue occurs. In other words there's nothing the extension can do in those cases.